# How can I update a text file when I move from gridview to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I read text to the GridView and then move this text from the GridView to TextBoxes to edit. How can I replace the changed data from selection line and save to my text file?

this is my write file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"WriteLines2.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(this.id.Text + "#" + this.judul.Text + "#" + this.isi.Text);
    }
}
```

this is my gridview

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("WriteLines2.txt");
    string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split('#');
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (string c in columnnames)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(c);
    }
    string newline;
    while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        string[] values = newline.Split('#');
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = values[i];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    file.Close();
    GridView.DataSource = dt;
```

this is my grid view move to textbox

```
private void GridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = GridView.SelectedRows[0];
    id.Text = dr.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    // or simply use column name instead of index
    //dr.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    judul.Text = dr.Cells["judul"].Value.ToString();
    isi.Text = dr.Cells["subjek"].Value.ToString();
    //textBox4.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    GridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Text file or textbox?

Comment: Can you post the code related to the textview, gridview and textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `GridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;` when you initialize your DataGridView and not during the `CellContentClick`. Then use the `SelectionChanged Event` instead of the `CellContentClick Event` and use `CurrentCell.RowIndex` for the index:

```
private void GridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = GridView.Rows[GridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
    id.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    judul.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    isi.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Your `buton1_Click` adds a new values to the end of your file. I'm not sure if that is what you want.